# 504 when calling a webservice from JBoss EAP 4.3

Tags: java, jboss

#### Background

I have a web service that returns a list of users and some values for each user.
One of these values is retrieved from a Cisco Unified Presence (CUP) server via a PUT request.
I'm using jersey to send the PUT request from my webservice to the CUP server.

#### The Problem

I get a "504 Gateway Timeout The requested URL couldn't be resolved" error when I send the PUT request to the CUP server while running inside JBoss.
When I run the same code from my command line, it works.
Is this a problem with my JBoss EAP 4.3 configuration?
If yes, how do I resolve it?

#### Some Code

Here is the code I am using to send the PUT request:

```
    final Client client = Client.create();
    final ClientResponse clientResponse;
    final String requestBody = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><session><password>thepassword</password></session>";
    final WebResource webResource = client.resource("http://host:8082/presence-service/users/username/session");
    final WebResource.Builder webResourceBuilder;

    webResourceBuilder = webResource.accept(MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE);
    webResourceBuilder.type(MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE);

    clientResponse = webResourceBuilder.put(
        ClientResponse.class,
        requestBody);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:  I added the target host to the **http.nonProxyHosts** value in the conf/local.properties file.

Discussion: It appears that JBoss was attempting to resolve the host name with an external DNS Server, but the host name with which I'm testing is only visible internally and was not visible to the DNS Server in question.